google authentication working, but not showing at the dashboard
I'm making an app with expo and I want to authenticate in the app using email/password or using google.
I added email and password authentication using this code:
// this is the function for initiating firebase
function init_firebase(){
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ' AIzaSyCs-qNMrjikN5VqKdY737K22QSsT9MmtGI ',
    authDomain: 'tiod-app.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://tiod-app-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/',
    projectId: 'tiod-app',
    appId: '1:659850692368:android:bf812065131d214dfb0795',
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
  });
  return {app, auth};
}
export const firebase = init_firebase();

and
// the function for signing up
async function Signup_email(navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>, email: string, password: string){
    const login = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(firebase.auth, email, password).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
    if (login){return;}
    navigation.navigate('Main', {email});
}
// the function for logging in
async function Login_email(navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>, email: string, password: string,
){
  const app = firebase;
  if (!app){return;}
  const login = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(app.auth, email, password).catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
  if (!login){return;}
  navigation.navigate('Loading', login.user.toJSON());
}

and it worked well, but for authentication with google, I realized that the function that is used for redirecting to sign in (which is signInWithRedirect) is undefined since it affects the DOM.
so I used @react-native-google-signin/google-signin to attempt to do the same thing. I managed to
use google to sign in using this code:
async function Login_google(navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>){
  const result = await GoogleSignin.signIn().catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
  if (!result){return;}
  navigation.navigate('Loading', result.user);
}

also, I configured google signin in main
    GoogleSignin.configure({webClientId: "659850692368-bf2itlqkbbroq5cd3e8lq969qtk8ks5i.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        googleServicePlistPath: "../GoogleService-Info.plist",
    })

but for some reason, after logging in with google the user dashboard in firebase is still empty

After logging in using google signin, you need to also log into Firebase using GoogleAuthProvider.credential.
here is how I fixed the auth function:
async function Login_google(navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>){
  const login = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
  const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(login.idToken);
  const result = await signInWithCredential(firebase.auth, credential);
  navigation.navigate('Loading', result.user.toJSON());
}

